# Express triangle sides given a circle and an angle. Then, find its geometric locus.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, locus

[image]

Given the equation of the circle:

$$x^2 + (y-a)^2 = a^2$$

- How to express $ON$ and $PN$ in terms of $a$ and $\phi$ ?
- Hence, how to find the locus of $P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right triangles △OAN and △ONP to derive ON and PN, respectively,

$$ ON = 2a \tan \phi$$
$$ PN = ON \tan \phi = 2a \tan^2 \phi$$

To find the locus of P, write the function of P in its polar coordinates, with the help of right triangle △ONP,

$$ON^2+PN^2 = 4a^2 (\tan^2 \phi + \tan^4 \phi)=r^2$$

After simplification,

$$ r = 2a \frac{\sin\phi}{\cos^2\phi} $$

Then, it is more convenient to view above curve in its $xy$-coordinates with

$$x=r\cos\phi,\space y=r\sin\phi$$

which is just,

$$ x^2 = 2ay$$

Hence, P is a parabola.

Comment: Does this mean that the angle $\sphericalangle OAN$ is also $\phi$ ?

Comment: Correct. Because △OAN and △BON are similar.

Comment: You mean $\bigtriangleup OAN$ and $\bigtriangleup PON$ ? :) Any idea on how to find a locus of $P$ ?

Comment: Please see the added in the answer.

Comment: The solution in the book is $x^2 = 2ay$. But anyway I will try to use your steps to get to that point

Comment: Right, I switched x and y

Comment: By the way, I now realized that the parametric equations of $P$ are actually already determined by $ON$ being the $x$-coordinate, and $PN$ being the $y$-coordinate... All this effort :')